# KafkaProducer 0.10.0.0, JavaDoc states that BufferExhaustedException should be thrown

Tags: java, apache-kafka, javadoc

i am currently working on a Kafka Integration, looking at the send javadoc it states the following for KafkaProducer's send API :

@throws BufferExhaustedException If `block.on.buffer.full=false` and the buffer is full.

However looking at the 0.10.0.0 code I could not locate the place where this exception is actually thrown, so it seems to me that i would have to set max.block.ms to 0 and expect a TimeoutException instead in order to work in a non-blocking way.

Below is a snippet from the BufferPool class in version 0.8.2.1 clearly we can see that a BufferExhaustedException is being thrown if no memory is available:

[0.8.2.1 snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BubZR.jpg)

On the other hand in version 0.10.0.0 the code is as follows:

[0.10.0.0 snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yBLb.jpg)

Am I correct in saying the way forward should be to set max.block.ms to 0 and expect a TimeoutException or is BufferExhaustedException still supported?

If BufferExhaustedException is no longer supported it should at the very least be removed from the send API's Javadoc.

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on the dev mailing list: https://kafka.apache.org/contact.html